# How to build openFrameworks as a shard library on macOS

Tags: c++, makefile, openframeworks

I'm trying to build OF as a shared library (.so) in macOS.

I added the following to my app's `config.make` file.

```
APPNAME = myApp.so

PROJECT_LDFLAGS = -rdynamic -shared -undefined dynamic_lookup

PROJECT_OPTIMIZATION_CFLAGS_RELEASE = -O3
```

But when I build the project using `make`, it actually generates an Application file `myApp.so.app` which is not a shared library.

How can I properly build OF as a shared library in macOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could successfully build OF as a shared library with the following:

```
APPNAME = myApp.so
PROJECT_CFLAGS = -Wall
PROJECT_LDFLAGS = -dynamiclib -Wl,-undefined -Wl,dynamic_lookup
PROJECT_OPTIMIZATION_CFLAGS_RELEASE = -O3
```